# How to load relative source in WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp, httpclient

I'm using HttpClient to get html string and use WebView's navigateToString method to show this page. I know I can use WebView load this page directly, but I would need to do some processing on that page before it's shown in WebView.

So, I faced a question. The web page quotes some css/js files in header, but I saw that 'href' value is relative path. Then the page will not show correctly in WebView.

[Updated]
For example, I'm using HttpClient to request a URI (`http://example.com`), then I will get the whole html page string. I will do some operations on this html string. After that, I will use `WebView.NavigateToString(htmlpage)` method to show this page. But if you check its head tag, there will be some `<link>` tag, its href value is relative path(/style-a/1.css), not absolute path. Then you will find that the html page doesn't show correctly in WebView.

Could someone give me a solution/code sample?

@Pedro Lamas, rene, Barett, moi_meme, Shachaf.Gortler Please do not put my question on hold. I didn't break any SO rules. My question was very clear. I think you do this, it's because you do not know how to answer my question. That's ok. If you don't know, you could choose not to answer it, but please do not put it on hold.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with NavigateToString method. There is, however, NavigateToLocalStreamUri method where you can provide your own resolver for every relative link on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set address of your Link or Scripts tag with `ms-appx-web://` and put address after that with additional ***[  /  ]*** .

for example in this case you can use :

```
<script src="ms-appx-web:///Assets/FolderName/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and also for link can use :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ms-appx-web:///style-a/1.css">
```